# Python plot multiple z-test result with confidence interval (visualize A/B test results)

Tags: seaborn, abtest, python-visual

[what I want to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoOAP.png)

Hi, I want to visualize results for one A/B test. The experiment tracks 4 metrics, and I want to show them in one plot altogether. The schema of my dataframe is:

test_control | metric1 | metric2 | metric3 | metric4

Does anyone know how to plot, by matplotlib, pandas or seaborn?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show the full dataframe? Your question is a bit unspecific here, are you supposed to calculate the confidence interval from the data frame?

Answer (score 0):

I found it's probably easier to be done in R.
In python, I calculated the error bar and then used matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar to plot:

## get CI

```
kpi_map = {'kpi':[], 'mean_diff':[], 'err':[], 'pval':[]}
for col in metrics:
    sp1 = df.loc[df['test_control']=='test'][col]
    sp2 = df.loc[df['test_control']=='control'][col]
    std1 = np.std(sp1, ddof=1)
    std2 = np.std(sp2, ddof=1)
    mean_diff_std = (std1**2/len(sp1) + std2**2/len(sp2)) **0.5
    mean_diff = sp1.mean() - sp2.mean()     
    kpi_map['kpi'].append(col)
    kpi_map['mean_diff'].append(mean_diff)
    kpi_map['err'].append(1.96*mean_diff_std)
```

## plot

```
df_kpi = pd.DataFrame(data = kpi_map)
plt.errorbar(y=df_kpi['kpi'], x=df_kpi['mean_diff'], xerr=df_kpi['err'], fmt='o', elinewidth=2, capsize=4, capthick=2)
```